# UseExceptionHandler does not handle all exceptions

Tags: asp.net-core

My application uses the recommended exception handling in ASP.NET Core:

```cs
            if (_webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");
                app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");

                app.UseHsts();
            }
```

I have discovered that apparently exceptions in my Custom Cookie Validation Handler are not handled by the exception handler mechanism:

```cs
   public class MyCustomCookieRequestValidationHandler : CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        public override Task ValidatePrincipal(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
        {
            throw new Exception()
        }
```

Why does the Exception Handler not process this exception?
How can I still display an error page for cases like this?

edit: as requested the full more or less default config file

```cs
    public class MyStartup
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

        public MyStartup(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // ...
            // default registrations like options here
            // ...

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });

            services
                .ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
                {
                    // cookie settings
                    options.Events = new MyCustomCookieRequestValidationHandler();
                });

            services
                .AddScoped<MyCustomCookieRequestValidationHandler>();

           // ...
           // mvc registrations
           // ...
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (_webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseForwardedHeaders(
                    new ForwardedHeadersOptions
                    {
                        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor,
                        ForwardLimit = 1
                    }
                );

                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");
                app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");

                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseResponseCaching();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: You add your handler after your error handling block?

Comment: Can you show the full middleware pipeline from your `Configure` method?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen CookieAuthenticationEvents are registered as service, the exception handler is a middleware. So there is no order in this case.

Comment: @poke it's just the default startup, but I added it. thanks!